# Sed only one-liner

Tags: bash, text, sed

I need to use **sed** to parse out some text.  I can't use cut because of some syntax it causes with Ansible in this particular case.  I was hoping to achieve this just with sed.  This is a single line of text.

```
    "_ref": "record:host/ZG5zLmhvc3QkLl9kZWZhdWx0Lm5ldC5kdHZvcHMuYW5keXRlc3QwMg:pootest02.catt.net/Internal"
```

I need to print out everything after the third "(quote) and before the third :(colon).

My expected outcome should be:

```
    record:host/ZG5zLmhvc3QkLl9kZWZhdWx0Lm5ldC5kdHZvcHMuYW5keXRlc3QwMg
```

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this part of a JSON file? If so , you are better off using a tool that understands JSON, like `jq -r '.ref / ":" | .[0:2] | join(":")'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sed -r 's/^".*".*"(.*):.*/\1/'
```

but if it's a JSON like chepner said in comments, really try [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working beautifully:

`sed -n -e 's#.*\(record:[^:]\+\):.*#\1#p'`